# symfony cannt join related tables in manytomany relationship

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I cannot join tables(`Products` and `Category`) in ManyToMany relationship.

[My Entities](https://gist.github.com/gghhh456/ce74b43b0a8b3ce10353)

I get this error message when I try to join them

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 511: Error: Expected Literal, got 'JOIN'
```

My Repository

```
public function GetProductsList($productid){
$fields = array['product.product','category.category']
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select($fields)
        ->from('TestMyBundle:product','product')
        ->innerJoin('TestMyBundle:category','category')
        ->where('product.productid=:productid')
        ->setParameter('productid',$productid)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
return $query;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join looks wrong and I don't see why you need an hardcoded array there. May as well just put the entity aliases directly in the select. I would write that as:

```
public function GetProductsList($productid){

    $result = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('product', 'category')
        ->from('TestMyBundle:product','product')
        ->join('product.categories','category') // making an assumption your product entity has getCategories()
        ->where('product.productid=:productid')
        ->setParameter('productid',$productid)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $result;
}
```

Should work then.

Note that when you get problems like this it's useful to do something like ->getSQL() instead of getQuery() and var_dump the SQL to see what the querybuilder is producing, makes it easier to debug.

Comment: It says class product.category not found.

Comment: Can you please post the product & category entity relationships.

Comment: Also note the join in my references product.categories (which should be correct for a many to many if you have set it up corrrectly) - not product category.

Comment: I did already... i didnt understand reference "product.categories"

Comment: Okay I got it... Thanks